# Get Closest Color and then turn it into color specific name

Tags: c#

I am using this function, I found on the internet but I want to add more colors to it such as: pink, beige, white, black etc.. How can I adapt this code to my needs?

```
public static string ColorName(Color c)
        {
            List<float> hues = new List<float>()
            { 0, 15, 35, 44, 54, 63, 80, 160, 180, 200, 244, 280, 350, 360};
            List<string> hueNames = new List<string>()
            { "red", "orange-red", "orange", "yellow-orange", "yellow",
            "yellow-green",   "green"  , "blue-green" , "cyan", "blue",
            "violet", "purple", "red" };

            float h = c.GetHue();
            float s = c.GetSaturation();
            float b = (c.R * 0.299f + c.G * 0.587f + c.B * 0.114f) / 256f;

            string name = s < 0.35f ? "pale " : s > 0.8f ? "vivid " : "";
            name += b < 0.35f ? "dark " : b > 0.8f ? "light " : "";
            for (int i = 0; i < hues.Count - 1; i++)
                if (h >= hues[i] && h <= hues[i + 1])
                {
                    name += hueNames[i];
                    break;
                }
            return name;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That may work well for hsb in determining light/dark pale/vivid, but not so well for pink/yellow blue/orange. The color space is set up as an xy plot here. For finding closest color, look at the CIELab color space. It allows for a Euclidean distance calculation which can identify things like yellow as being closer to beige than a similar saturation value of an orange hue.